# WiFi only works after suspend. Ubuntu 14.04 on HP Pavilion

Tags: 14.04, networking, hp, wifi-hardware-switch

I'm using a HP Pavilion G6 with Ubuntu 14.04. My WiFi is not working, but magically I found that when I suspended the laptop it was enabled and When I shutdown my laptop again disconnected. I again suspended it and got the WiFi.

This happens again and again. How to solve it?

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
Kernel driver in use: wl
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: I have seen three of these questions in the last two days.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Just now I edited and updated my output. please help me.